# Most popular products of store , array from table 1 and shown on table 2

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show most popular items of store on website 
Table 1 is Last buy items , Table 2 is Products details

First query From Table 1 : `SELECT item_id FROM $tableName ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 5`
**Result:** 
1156 , 1146 , 1749 , 1325 , 1952

**What I must to do for showing This result for MostPopulars Products from Table 2 ?**
Last Result Visitors can View ,for example:
Example_Name_item1156 - Price:15$
Example_Name_item1146 - Price:38$
Example_Name_item1749 - Price:29$
Example_Name_item1952 - Price:17$

*I work with PHP and MySQL*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.* from products p
inner join (SELECT item_id, views FROM $tableName) as i on i.item_id = p.item_id
ORDER BY i.views DESC 
LIMIT 5
```